# how to change the font size of edwin editor?

Tags: debian, font-size, mit-scheme, edwin

I am using edwin editor which comes with mit gnu scheme. When I open it on my Debian system with the following command "scheme -edwin -edit", I get the editor window, but it has extremely small font size.

Even after several searches I could not figure out how to change the default font size of the editor. I tried the following command ((ref-command set-default-font) "200") but to no avail. I could find a reference here http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.844/spring05-6844/handouts/edwin.ini but it doesn't help much.

How can I change the font size in edwin?

Comment: alternatively, you can use Emacs, which has much better and more natural support for changing fonts and font sizes, and which Edwin is a very barebones imitation of. Simply open up a .scm file, and do `M-x run-scheme` and you're set to go.

Comment: Consider also [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/247837/604809), which worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. I finally managed to do it by using the entire XLFD in my init file.:

`((ref-command set-font) "-monotype-andale mono-medium-r-normal--16-0-0-0-c-0-iso8859-5")`

Here is a link to emac's manual about fonts where they explain about XLFD:

http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Fonts.html

You can use `M-x font-apropos` under edwin to search for fonts. And `M-x set-font` to set them.

`C-h a` is the command apropos. Where you can search, and get help on commands under edwin.